# How to create a material of horizontal black and white lines

Tags: materials, export, wireframe, svg

I am trying to reproduce it by my own but I can not understand how to switch off vertical edges in render options inside of freestyle svg exporter? Any thoughts?  Many thanks in advance!

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/freestyle/export_svg.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a 'Texture Coordinate' node and plug it into a 'Mapping' node. Now you are able to split the output vectors with a 'Separate XYZ' node. If you plug b.e. the 'z'-Value of the 'Separate XYZ' node in the vector of a 'Checker Texture' node, you will get strips along the z-axis, same for the x, y.. with some vector math you can easily manipulate the result

[image: Shader Setup]